# Sorting report according to parameter in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a simple report with two fields: ID and NAME.
I want to sort the detail by ID or NAME depending on a parameter selected by the user in runtime.

I've tried doing something like this:

```
<sortField name="sort" type="Variable"/>

<variable name="sort" class="java.lang.String">
    <variableExpression>
        <![CDATA[$P{ord}.equals("name") ? $F{entity}.getName() : $F{entity}.getId().toString()]]>
    </variableExpression>
</variable>
```

EDIT 1: I'm passing the datasource as a parameter, I don't execute the sql query from JasperReports. 
I think I could pass the datasource alredy sorted to JasperReports, but i'd like to sort the data directly from the report.

EDIT 2: I reviewed the previous code and works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a Parameter "Sort_order" with default value "ID" and add the order by clause in your query.

```
  SELECT...
  FROM..
  ORDER BY $P!{Sort_order} DESC
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I do not execute the sql query from JasperReports

Answer (score 0):

You can use ORDER BY clause in your SELECT. However sometimes you need your data to be sorted by jasper because of internalization or similar things. One way how to solve this problem is to select special columns for sorting like that (POSTGRESQL):

```
SELECT 
    id, name,
    (CASE WHEN $P!{Sort_order}='id' THEN id ELSE null END) sort_id,
    (CASE WHEN $P!{Sort_order}='name' THEN name ELSE null END) sort_name
FROM
    your_table;
```

then you set sorting by columns `sort_name` and `sort_id`